# Layering Canvas on another Canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Im currently doing something that goes like:

- create a canvas and append it to a divider
- set a background image via CSS on that canvas.
- draw a hexgrid on the canvas
- draw PNGs on the canvas.
- animate those PNGs to display "movement".

However, its a pain having to redraw the entire canvas including the non-moving PNGs.

Im wondering if it would be smarter or better to have a single canvas for the Background/hexgrid and create the PNGs on additional, small canvas elements which are then zIndex'ed on top of the Background canvas. I then could make the animations (PNGs moving) easier.

However, im running into problems in regards to actually placing the "new" canvas's at the right x/y coordinates of the Background canvas.

```
this.drawShipImage = function(name, id, x, y){

    var div = document.getElementById("grid");
        // initial, big canvas with background is created elsewhere but has the same width/height than "grid"

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.id = name + id;
        canvas.width = 30;
        canvas.height = 30;
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.zIndex = 1;    

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.scale(0.75, 0.75);
        context.drawImage(ship, 0, 0);

    div.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

Basicly, this function has 2 important Parameters, that is the x/y Parameter where the new canvas SHOULD be drawn in context to the width/height of the Background canvas.
However im unable to conclude a way to get the Image to appear at the right coordinates.

I suppose the only way it could work is adding 
**canvas.style.margin = x/y-ish**
into the mix ?

Comment: Why not only use 2 canvases? One for the background and the other one for the PNGs'... And by the way, you're not using `top` and `left` properties to position the multiple canvases?

Comment: Can you explain top/left properties, how they would help my cause if i use 2 canvas' only ?

Comment: They will not help with the 2 canvases but with the multiple(small) canvases as you're trying to put each canvases on the background canvas.

Comment: Use a single canvas ... the greatest advantage of using the canvas element is to avoid unnecessary DOM ... you will have to redraw it anyway and it will give you a better performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a second canvas (or just an img element holding your background) might be a good solution since your background will be redrawn less frequently than your animated foreground.

This is particularly true if your device has a GPU because the background element will be cached in the GPU and will redraw very quickly as compared with the relatively slower drawings on your animating foreground canvas.

You can use the CSS `position` property to stack 2 elements.

1. Wrap your 2 canvases (or canvas + img elements) in a wrapping div.
2. Set the wrapper div's `position` property to relative (meaning children will be positioned relative to the wrapper instead of relative to the page).
3. Set the 2 canvases (or canvas + img elements) `position` to 'absolute' (meaning they are subject to being positioned relative to the wrapper).
4. Set the `top` & `left` properties of the child elements to 0 so they will overlap. The default top & left values are zero, so assigning them to zero is optional--but explicitly assigning them to zero is more clear.

**HTML**

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <canvas id="canvasBottom" width=300 height=200></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvasTop" width=300 height=200></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #wrapper{
        position:relative;
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
    }
    #canvasTop,#canvasBottom{
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
        border:1px solid green;
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
    }
    #canvasTop{
        border:1px solid red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Layer canvas elements via **KineticJS**

It's really easy to layer canvas elements via `KineticJS` from Eric Rowell. It's a very useful library to work with the HTML5 canvas element.

The lib is not maintained anymore but its very stable.
Get it here: [KineticJS Download](http://kineticjs.com/)

Find the reference here: [KineticJS Reference](http://agavestorm.com/kineticjs/)

If you search a little bit on the web for examples you will clearly understand that every node in KineticJS is an own canvas element. This library relies on layering canvas elements via groups and so on.